# Why am I getting different results from a query vs. a view

Tags: mysql, view, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

The base problem I'm facing is that I need the latest record for each item.

A little setup... MySQL 5.6.14.

I need to create two views (because MySQL won't let me have a subquery in a view).  My first query sets up the data like this.

```
select 
    `inventoryrecords`.`inventoryrecordid` AS `inventoryrecordid`,
    `inventoryrecords`.`logicaldeviceid` AS `logicaldeviceid`,
    `inventoryrecords`.`passrfid` AS `passrfid`,
    `inventoryrecords`.`tagepc` AS `tagepc`,
    `inventoryrecords`.`currentstate` AS `currentstate`,
    `inventoryrecords`.`statedateutc` AS `statedateutc`,
    `inventoryrecords`.`ownerobjectid` AS `ownerobjectid`,
    `inventoryrecords`.`ownerobjecttype` AS `ownerobjecttype`
from
    `inventoryrecords`
where
    1
order by `inventoryrecords`.`statedateutc` desc
```

Then I can restrict everything to just the last record for each TagEPC with my "real" query like this.

```
select 
    `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`inventoryrecordid` AS `inventoryrecordid`,
    `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`logicaldeviceid` AS `logicaldeviceid`,
    `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`passrfid` AS `passrfid`,
    `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`tagepc` AS `tagepc`,
    `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`currentstate` AS `currentstate`,
    `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`statedateutc` AS `statedateutc`,
    `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`ownerobjectid` AS `ownerobjectid`,
    `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`ownerobjecttype` AS `ownerobjecttype`
from
    `lastinventoryrecords_step1`
group by `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`tagepc`
order by `lastinventoryrecords_step1`.`statedateutc` desc
```

When I try to select * from the "real" view, I do not get the data I expect.  However when I run the query with the sub-query in a window I do.

```
select * from ( 
lastinventoryrecords_step1 )
group by tagepc
order by statedateutc desc
```

yields incorrect data whereas

```
select * from (
    select 
        inventoryrecordid,
        logicaldeviceid,
        passrfid,
        tagepc,
        currentstate,
        statedateutc,
        ownerobjectid,
        ownerobjecttype
    from
        inventoryrecords
    where
        1
    order by statedateutc desc ) as t1
group by tagepc
order by statedateutc desc
```

yields the right data.

What in the heck is going on?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

You're using GROUP BY in a non-deterministic way. You `GROUP BY tagepc`, but what value for the other columns do you expect?

MySQL permits this kind of query, but MySQL chooses a row from the group arbitrarily. In practice, it tends to be the *first* row in the group, as they are stored physically.

But in the case when you query through the view, the view stores its results in a temporary table, probably in a different physical order than the data in the original table.

Note that http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html says:

> `ORDER BY` is permitted in a view definition, but it is ignored if you select from a view using a statement that has its own `ORDER BY`.

So the query run by the view to populate the temp table ignores your view's `ORDER BY`, and since you used `GROUP BY` it probably takes values from arbitrary rows in the underlying table.

How to fix this? Stop running ambiguous `GROUP BY` queries. Any column referenced in your select-list should either by (a) listed in the `GROUP BY` clause, or (b) inside a grouping function like `MAX()` or something.

I don't know what you expect this query to do, or why you're using `GROUP BY` in the first place. So I can't offer any more specific advice.

---

Re your comment:

Thanks for the clarification. This is a pretty common type of SQL question. I created the tag [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) on StackOverflow and now it has close to a thousand questions. The tag exists on dba.stackexchange.com, but with fewer questions so far.

Here's a solution:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM inventoryrecords AS i
JOIN (SELECT TagEPC, MAX(StateDateUTC) AS StateDateUTC
      FROM inventoryrecords
      GROUP BY TagEPC ORDER BY NULL) AS maxi USING (TagEPC, StateDateUTC);
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  What I'm trying to do is this... each record has a TagEPC, a CurrentState and a StateDateUTC.  The data models a product being put into or taken out of a cabinet.  The TagEPC is the product, the Current State is whether the item is In or Out and the State Date is when it happened.  I want the latest record (based on StateDateUTC) for each TagEPC.

I found I can get what I want if I don't use a View, but my query is just ungodly ugly.